# eclipse does not work in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, installation, eclipse

I have search on a lot of similar problem in this website and other but I always have problem my *eclipse 4.3 64 bit* does not work in my ubuntu 12.04 64 bit and does not show me any error
just when i click on the icon eclipse luncher

i dont see any error,the file is executable

`java -version`

```
java version "1.7.0_25"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.3.10) (7u25-2.3.10-1ubuntu0.12.04.2)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.7-b01, mixed mode)
```

`which java`

```
/usr/bin/java
```

I mentioned that when i try to execute some jars java it works well
but when i try to execute direclty by terminal `./eclipse/eclipse` it gives me
no such file or directory :(
please give me some help its 3 days i have some problem

Answer (score 0):

### It won't work if you placed eclipse folder other than `/` partition.

For example if i placed eclipse folder in the desktop,i have to follow the below steps.

- So go into the eclipse folder via terminal,

  ```
    cd ~/Desktop/eclipse
  ```
- Give the executable permission for the file eclipse,

  ```
    sudo chmod 777 eclipse
  ```
- Then run the eclipse file by,

  ```
    sudo ./eclipse
  ```

Comment: i did it and unfortunately it does not work

./eclipse 
bash: ./eclipse: No such file or directory

Comment: what are the files inside that directory.Did you find any eclipse file?

Comment: yeah yeah i have an icon eclipse launcher I already work with eclipse in ubunto 9 when i install new ubunto does not work

Comment: it should be like this http://i.imgur.com/Tu1Ecuc.png

Comment: yes it is like that

Comment: then follow my answer.

Comment: in my case path to the directory is ~/android/androidlinux/eclipse

Comment: Hola and last it works Thnks a lot Mr Avinash
But it work without do what you says i download new eclipse and it works